# Characterization for the convergence in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space such that the convergence is characterized by the following equivalence

\begin{equation}
x_n\to x\qquad\text{ if and only if }\qquad f(x_n)\to f(x) \text{ for all }f\in T, \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $T$ is a given family of function from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$, called "testing functions."

Now, let $X_n$ a sequence of random variable with values in the metric space $E$. Is there a relation between the convergence in distribution of the sequence $X_n$ and the previous equivalence (1)?

In particolare we know that $X_n\to X$ in distribution if and only if

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_n)]\to \mathbb{E}[g(X)]\text{ for all }g\in\mathcal{C}_b(E).\tag{2}$$

How can we "simplify" (2) using (1)?